# Service is not registered in the servicecollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, service-provider

I do not understand why after i am adding a service to `IServiceCollection` , when i try to get back a reference to it using `ServiceProvider` the value is null.

**Startup**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    Startup.ConfigureServicesForDebugging?.Invoke(services);

    try
    {

        services.AddTransient<HttpWrapper>();

        ServiceProvider prov = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        HttpWrapper returned=prov.GetRequiredService<HttpWrapper>();

        if (returned == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("is null");
        }
        else Console.WriteLine(returned.Test);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

**HttpWrapper**

```
public class HttpWrapper
{
    public HttpClient cl = new HttpClient();
    public string Test = "aaa";
}
```

Why is  the returned service  null? I first thought that its because its `Transient` so it would be per request..so no request at that stage -> null.
But it still returns null when using `AddSingleton` too.
Why is that service null?

**P.S** What i need is :

```
public class TransientService{
public HttpClient sharedProperty;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  HttpClient client=new HttpClient();
  services.AddTransient( new TransientService{ sharedProperty=client});
}
```

I need a service that is transient but all its instances share a field ( `HttpClient` in my case)

**PS 2** After i have changed from `GetService` to `GetRequiredService` i get the `InvalidOperationException` that the service was not registered.Why would that happen ? I have also changed from the to the non lambda insertion: 
services.AddTransient() still with the same problem.

Comment: You are registering a function, not a service. The function returns the same instance each time as if it were a singleton. What *do* you want to do ?

Comment: I need to add one instance of the `HttpWrapper` ,which is transient.I thought you could use the delegate overload as a custom way to build the service.

Comment: If it's one instance, it's *not* transient. That overload registers a factory method but in this case it returns the same instance, making it a singleton

Comment: I have updated the post.I need  a transient service that refers only one `HttpClient`

Comment: And again, that's the same contradictory statement. If instead you mean `I want to create a typed httpclient that uses HttpClient properly` you're doing it wrong. There are several articles that explain how to use HttpClientFactory for this and *why* you should do so - if the DNS to IP mapping changes your HttpClient will stop working.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian the article [Use HttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) shows how to create a typed Http client that handles HttpClient properly. With a *single* line `services.AddHttpClient<ICatalogService, CatalogService>()` you get proper lifecycle handling for your wrapper/service class

Comment: I added an example using HttpClientFactory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem.

`GetService` will return null if the requested service hasn't been registered. If `GetRequiredService` was called, it would throw an exception.

There are two problems in this code.

First, this line :

```
services.AddTransient(y =>wrapper);
```

registers a *factory function* that returns the same HttpWrapper instance, not the HttpWrapper instance itself. That function will return whatever `wrapper` contains.

Second, `AddTransient` says this is a transient service and yet, the same instance will be returned every time.

If the same service is used every time, the registration should use `AddSingleton` :

```
services.AddSingleton<HttpWrapper>();
```

If a *new* instance is needed each time, it should be :

```
services.AddTransient<HttpWrapper>();
```

**Test Code**

I used this code to test the problem and can't reproduce it :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    try
    {
        HttpWrapper wrapper = new HttpWrapper();
        services.AddTransient(provider => wrapper);

        ServiceProvider prov = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        HttpWrapper returned = prov.GetRequiredService<HttpWrapper>();

        Console.WriteLine("No problem");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

The class will be created without any issues. The only way for this to fail is for `wrapper` to be null. I use `GetRequiredService` to force an exception if no registration is found.

**Typed Http Clients**

From the comments it appears that the *real* issue is how to create a service that uses HttpClient properly. Reusing the same instance will improve performance as it keeps existing TCP connections in a connection pool. It still needs to be recycled periodically though to handle changing DNS addresses. Using a transient HttpClient is bad but so is using a single HttpClient instance.

The HttpClientFactory takes care of both concerns by pooling and recycling the *HttpClientHandler* instances that actually perform the HTTP requests for each HttpClient. The article [Use HttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) explains how this works but long story short, simply adding :

```
services.AddHttpClient<ICatalogService, CatalogService>();
```

Will ensure that every instance of `CatalogService` will get a properly handled `HttpClient`. All `CatalogService` needs to do is accept an `HttpClient` in its constructor and use it in its methods :

```
public class CatalogService : ICatalogService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public CatalogService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<Catalog> GetCatalogItems(int page, int take, 
                                           int? brand, int? type)
    {
        ....
        var responseString = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
        ...
    }
}
```

The `AddHttpClient` extension method is available in the [Microsoft.Extensions.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/) package

Adapting this to the question, `HttpWrapper` should accept an HttpClient parameter in its constructor :

```
public class HttpWrapper 
{
    private readonly HttpClient _cl;
    public HttpWrapper(HttpClient client)
    {
        _cl=client;
    }

    public string TestUrl = "aaa";

}
```

And get registered with `AddHttpClient` :

```
services.AddHttpClient<HttpWrapper>();
```

After that, it can be resolved with :

```
var returned = prov.GetRequiredService<HttpWrapper>();
```

Comment: In my code i  have added the service to the collection **before** i used the `ServiceProvider`.I need an instance it does not patter which instance.I have also tried using `AddSingleton` and it still returns a `null`.I need any instance of that particular type of service.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian You registered a factory method that returns a single instance. In any case, no repro.

Comment: When i am using like you said `GetRequiredService` on my code i get the `InvalidOperationException` ,that the service was not registered.Why would that happen ?